# Aligning website content to center

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with aligning.
This is my code.

Html:

```
<div id="alt">
<p>this is a sample text</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#alt{
display:block; position: absolute; top: 400px; left:500px;  }
```

on using code everything looks fine. But when I reduce the zoom level of the browser. Its goes to the left. I want it to remain in the centre. Help me in solving this.

Comment: add some code, jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

For aligning website content to center,you have to put all content in one div say main div and apply a below css to it

```
.main
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `left:50%` instead of `left:500px;`
css:

```
#alt{
display:block; position: absolute; top: 400px; left:50%;  }
```

If your container div has a fixed width then use `margin: 0 auto;`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X6Vxq/show

Answer (score 0):

Try the following style.

```
#alt
{
    display:block; 
    text-align: center;
    top: 400px; 
    left:500px;  
}

#alt p
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your content is present in a div, then you can give the position relative to the div and margin left and right to auto. Check the following code:

```
#alt {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard one to answer, since you don't seem to have given us enough info. Would you like the paragraph center *justified* or left-justified in a centered column?

To center justify, you can simply use:

```
#alt { text-align: center }
```

To create a centered block with the text left justified, use:

```
#alt {
width: 800px; /* Your desired width of the center block */
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry, i meant to align the whole block centre. 

Thanks.